# How to export Datetimepicker info to the datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime, methods, scheduling, datetimepicker

I'm creating a application that is scheduling pictures from user specified time/date to time/date.

How do I export the info from the DatetimePicker to the Datetime method?
And start all work from there?

If there is any better method please tell me, thank you!

Comment: is this the winforms [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx)?

Comment: Actually i use a modified WPF application that is compatible with DateTimePicker. 
So yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the date as a string:

```
string date= dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

and convert to DateTime:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Comment: Error 4 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Thanks for solution.
How do i make the method to read 
DateTime start = new DateTime(String);
Instead of
DateTime start = new DateTime(2009, 12, 9, 10, 0, 0);
??

Comment: `dateTimePicker1.Value` itself returns `DateTime` object.

Comment: Why not just use the `Value` property directly?  You might end up loosing precision if you convert to a string and then parse it again.